# What does a StringGrid's OnSetEditText event do?

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I thought OnSetEditText was fired whenever text in a cell changed. After setting a breakpoint and experimenting, I know that's wrong :-) So, first, when *is* this event fired?

Second, if I would like to have the text inside a grid cell continuously autosized, which event should I be coding to make this happen (note: I am using TMS's string grid derivative which includes a method for autosizing rows; I just have to figure out when to call it)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `OnSetEditText` event is fired every time the user changes the contents of the in-place editor control, assuming, of course, the control is editable (`goEditing in Options`). This is confirmed by the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnSetEditText), the VCL source code, and black-box verification.